# How to write in a csv file and know that a rental is active?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have to do a basic program for vehicle rent.
I have a class `Aluguer`  that receives the following atrributes:

1. start of renting
2. nickname of user
3. vehicle name
4. hourly price for rental

```
import time
now = time.time()

class Aluguer:
    def __init__(self, inicio, nickname, nome, preco_base):
        self.__inicio = inicio
        self.__nickname = nickname
        self.__nome = nome
        self.__preco_base = preco_base

    @property
    def inicio(self):
        self.__inicio = now
        return self.__inicio

    @property
    def nickname(self):
        return self.__nickname

    @property
    def nome(self):
        return self.__nome

    @property
    def preco_base(self):
        return self.__preco_base
```

To calculate the initial time of renting can I just do what I just did at:

```
@property
def inicio(self):
    self.__inicio = now
    return self.__inicio
```

Then, I have to do an update method that adds or updates (if they already exist) two new attributes to the `Aluguer` object: elapsed time and price.

I had written the following:

```
def update(self):
    tempo_fim = time.time()
    elapsed_seconds = tempo_fim - self.__inicio
    price = self.__preco_base
    valor = (elapsed_seconds / 3600) * price
```

When the user returns the vehicle, the `update` method will be executed and the information will be written in a csv file. After the registry in the file, the object will be deleted from the memory system.

How can I do it and how can I know if a rental is active?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Does one of your properties indicate that a rental is active? Or perhaps a combination?

Comment: If you delete the object when the lease ends, the fact that it exists is an indication that a lease is active, isn't it? How do you keep track of your vehicles?

Comment: When the user rents a vehicle, an Aluguer object is created with the following attributes (time start, user nickname, vehicle name and price per hour).

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like a long living process, I would use a structure as such:

```
import csv
import Aluguer

class Rentals:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rentals = {}
        
    def start_rental(self, inicio, nickname, nome, preco_base):
        new_rental = Aluguer(inicio, nickname, nome, preco_base, rental_id)
        rental_id = str(id(new_rental))
        self.rentals[rental_id] = new_rental
        rental.inicio()
        return rental_id
    
    def return_rental(self, rental_id):
        rental = self.rentals[rental_id]
        rental.update()
        file_name = "Dummy.csv"
        with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=rental.__dict__.keys())
            writer.writeheader()
            for data in rental.__dict__:
                writer.writerow(data)
```

You define a class `rentals` that holds all active rentals with a `start_rental` function that defines the rental and initializes it, and a `return_rental` function that updates it and writes it to csv. Therefore all active ones are the ones in the `rentals.rentals` list.

**Code above not functional and complete, just indicator

Comment: But, my rental is defined by start time, user nickname, vehicle name and price per hour. Where i am going to use that?

Comment: I updated the start_rental function, so it creates the new rental

Comment: In def return_rental(self, rental) how do i call the rental to return? In rentals list, I can have severall rents at same time.

Comment: If I were you, I would add a unique_id / booking_number etc. to the rental and refer to it by name, let me add it to the code

Comment: See update, now when you execute ```start_rental``` a ```rental_id``` is returned, and when you want to stop it, you call ```return_rental``` by the ```rental_id```

Comment: Ok. It is an academic basic project. Is there anyway to add an unique ID to the rentals withou import uuid? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I edited the code to use the id of the object